# How to delete / skip directory using Angular schematics?

Tags: javascript, angular-schematics

I have some files in my schematics template which should be generated only when a certain input options is present. e.g: db==true

Is there a way to skip these directories / files?

One solution is to remove them from the source using tree.delete(). However, that cannot remove dirs, only files.

What's the best way to do this:

What I want:

```
files/
 - file1
 - file2
 - dir // only if db==true
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

There is no such option, but you don't need it. If you don't want a directory to be created, remove its contents from the tree using tree.delete(). Schematics won't create empty directories, so the dir will be skipped.